# copying column values based on groups

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data set that looks as below,

| PTNUM | AGE_1 | AGE_2 | STATE_1 | STATE_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 15 | 18 | 1 | 2 |
| 123 | 15 | 23 | 2 | 2 |
| 123 | 23 | 28 | 2 | 3 |
| 124 | 15 | 17 | 1 | 1 |
| 124 | 17 | 25 | 1 | 1 |
| 124 | 25 | NA | 1 | 1 |
| 125 | 17 | 20 | 1 | 2 |

there are few points in the data that are to be corrected as for PTNUM 123 the second row should have been 18 instead of 15 (as shown below)

| PTNUM | AGE_1 | AGE_2 | STATE_1 | STATE_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 15 | 18 | 1 | 2 |
| 123 | ***18*** | 23 | 2 | 2 |
| 123 | 23 | 28 | 2 | 3 |
| 124 | 15 | 17 | 1 | 1 |
| 124 | 17 | 25 | 1 | 1 |
| 124 | 25 | NA | 1 | 1 |
| 125 | 17 | 20 | 1 | 2 |

I tried some thing like this

```
X6 <- X5 %>%
  group_by(PTNUM) %>%
  mutate(
    AGE1 = ifelse(lead(AGE2)==AGE1,AGE2, AGE1)
  )
```

where X6 and X5 were the datasets similar to the example given above, but it didn't work.
Can someone help with this,Thank you.

Comment: What is your final output? If you just need to update a few observations it may be easier to do that manually. Or quite frankly edit your csv file beforehand and read it in. To manually update the cell above you can do this. `X5[2,2] = 18`

Answer (score 0):

See my comment earlier if you only have a few observations that need updating. Otherwise if you're trying to programmatically update AGE_1 by the values in AGE_2 and have sorted your table appropriately. Here's how you would use lag/lead. It is lag in this case since you want to compare the previous AGE_1 value to the current one and update if they are the same.

```
X5 %>%
  arrange(PTNUM,AGE_1) %>% # Check to make sure it's sorted
  group_by(PTNUM) %>%
  mutate(AGE_1 = ifelse(AGE_1 != lag(AGE_1) | is.na(lag(AGE_1)), AGE_1, lag(AGE_2)))
```

```
# A tibble: 7 × 5
# Groups:   PTNUM [3]
  PTNUM AGE_1 AGE_2 STATE_1 STATE_2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   123    15    18       1       2
2   123    18    23       2       2
3   123    23    28       2       3
4   124    15    17       1       1
5   124    17    25       1       1
6   124    25    NA       1       1
7   125    17    20       1       2
```